# Function return type being string instead of string constant

Tags: typescript

This code:

```
interface ISomething {
 x: "a"|"b"; 
}


function f() {
  return {
    x: "a",
  };
}

function y(s: ISomething) {

}

const obj = f();
const obj2 = {
  x: "a",
};

const obj3 = "a";

y(obj); // Doesnt work
y(obj2); // Doesnt work
y({x: obj3}); // Works
```

Does not compile, showing this error:

> Argument of type '{ x: string; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ISomething'.
>     Types of property 'x' are incompatible.
>       Type 'string' is not assignable to type '"a" | "b"

Because `typeof f` is this:

```
f() => {x: string}
```

Why `f` returns `{x: string}` and not `{x: "a"}`? This code should be perfectly valid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you wrote, the compiler infers the type returned from `f()` to be `{ x: string; }`, but you can tell it to be more specific like so:

```
function f(): ISomething {
    return {
        x: "a",
    };
}
```

---

#### Edit

The compiler will infer this:

```
const a = "a"; // type of a is "a"
```

Because it's a `const` and cannot be later changed to a different value, but for example:

```
let a = "a"; // type of a is now string
```

Because you can later do something like:

```
a = "b";
```

The same here:

```
const obj2 = {
    x: "a",
};
```

Even though `obj2` is a `const`, you can then change the property:

```
obj2.x = "b";
```

Which is why the compiler infers `obj2.x` to be of type `string`.

You'll need to be more explicit to help the compiler understands what you want.  The compiler doesn't always infer types as we'd like it to.

Comment: I edited the code with three similar examples. One of them works. Is this intended?

Comment: Yes, both `obj` and `obj2` are of type `{ x: string; }`. The type of `obj3` is `"a"` so `{ x: obj3 }` is of type `{ x: "a" }`.

Comment: But this is making typescript throw unreasonable errors. Do you know if there is a discussion about this in their repositories?

Comment: I don't remember coming across anything about it in the ts repo. Check my revised answer.

Answer (score 1):

Because, in your `f` function, `"a"` is a string value, not a type.

If you want it to be a type, cast it to `"a"`.

```
function f() {
  return {
    x: "a" as "a",
  };
}
```

Comment: Nice feature... `"a" as "a"`.